# add a row with button in td dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add a row into a table with a button on the 3rd cell but it seems not to work

```
Script:

   function addRow()
      {
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable"),
          newRow = table.insertRow(table.length),
          cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
          cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1),
          cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2),
          name = document.getElementById("form").value,
          amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
          //this is where I assign a button
          delete1 = <input type='button' id='delete' value="delete">;

        cell1.innerHTML = name;
        cell2.innerHTML = amount;
        cell3.innerHTML = delete1;
      }
```

Comment: You need to make a valid string for the `delete1` variable. Use `delete1 = '<input type="button" id="delete" value="delete">';`

Comment: A tip: When things don't work like you expected check your Chrome Developer Console. More often than you think there will be the exact thing you did wrong

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_table_insertrow

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to make the variable `delete` a valid string:

```
delete1 = '<input type="button" id="delete" value="delete">';
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an example for your question.
You did serveral things wrong.
First you also need to declare the variables `newRow, cell1, cell2, cell3, name, amount, delete1`.
Like *The Codesee* said you have to format the string for the variable delete1 right.
I think with my example you can solve the rest.

```js
addRows();

function addRows(){
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    
    var row1 = table.insertRow(0);
    
    var cell1 = row1.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row1.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row1.insertCell(2);
    
    cell1.innerHTML = 'CELL 1';
    cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="button" id="delete" value="delete">'
    cell3.innerHTML = 'CELL 2';
}
```

```css
#myTable{border: 1px solid black;}

tr {background-color: yellow;}

td {border: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<table id="myTable"></table>
```